# How can i solve page not found problem on my wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am facing this problem whenever i click some of my pages. It shows: 
**The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

Comment: Have you renamed the pages after you had added them to the menu?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem with your .htaccess.
Add these codes to the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```